# How to declare an optional injected @input parameter?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am using a component factory to generate dynamic components on the fly. The factory is passed an array of data including input parameters for the generated component:

```
<app-field-factory [componentData]="componentSeedData"></app-field-factory>
```

This is working fine, and the "field factory" component processes the data. In each generated component I have something like this:

```
export class TextInputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() field_name: string;
  @Input() parent: string;
  @Input() validators: {};

  public fieldForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
      private injector: Injector,
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) {
    this.id = this.injector.get('id');
    this.field_name = this.injector.get('field_name');
    this.parent = this.injector.get('parent');
    this.validators = this.injector.get('validators');
  }
```

However, I can't work out how to make one of those inputs optional (ie. it may or may not exist). I've tried various things like adding a "?" and wrapping the `this.injector.get` line in a conditional. All I'm getting is a "*no provider for...*" error.

Let's say the `parent` input might, in some cases, not exist. How do I account for that within the generated component?

Comment: so you needed injector after all? why you used `@Input()` ? `injector` and `@Input()` are two unrelated things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `Injector.get` signature

```
abstract get<T>(token: Type<T>|InjectionToken<T>, notFoundValue?: T): T;
```

you can specify default value as second parameter:

```
this.parent = this.injector.get('parent', null);
```

In this case angular won't be complaining about unresolved provider. It will return `null`. Then you can simply use condition like `if (this.parent)`

Answer (score 4):

use the following code to make it optional:

```
@Input() parent?: string;
```

Comment: I tried that but I still get the *no provider* error. Also tried `@Optional` with the same result. I assume the problem is related to using injector..? I don't really understand..

Answer (score 0):

Every input in a component can be viewed as optional. If there's no binding defined when using a component the value will simply remain uninitialized or initialized with the default value.

```
class MyComponent {
   @Input() v;
```

// the binding `v` will be set to `32` during change detection
           // the binding `v` will remain unitialized

Note that `@Input()` are not automatically processed by Angular for dynamic components because correctly setting up input bindings requires knowing how a component will be used during compilation, this is not the case for dynamic components.

Also read:

- [The mechanics of property bindings update in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce)
- [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: What if I have an input like this:
[parentClass]="getparentClass"
and in some cases I just don't need to evaluate that parent class? 
Is there any way to make that input optional at an html-level?